# INVALID_RESOURCE_ID in paypal

Tags: java, android, paypal

I have make payments through PayPal native android mobile sdk. Below is the success response

```
{"response":{"state":"approved","id":"PAY-someID","create_time":"2017-06-21T18:01:33Z","intent":"sale"},"client":{"platform":"Android","paypal_sdk_version":"2.15.3","product_name":"PayPal-Android-SDK","environment":"sandbox"},"response_type":"payment"}
```

But when back-end wants to verify with the payment id i.e PAY-someID, it is throwing error json like below every time

```
[debug] application - verifyPayment mitemreqCppverifpmtrequest(PAY-someID)
[debug] application - verifpmtrequest case mendpointt https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-someID
[debug] application - tx.get.body{"name":"INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","message":"Requested resource ID was not found.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INVALID_RESOURCE_ID","debug_id":"someID"}
```

Below is the android code

```
private static final String CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT = PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX;

    private static PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration()
                .environment(CONFIG_ENVIRONMENT)
                .clientId(CONFIG_CLIENT_ID)
                // The following are only used in PayPalFuturePaymentActivity.
                .merchantName("Example Merchant")
                .merchantPrivacyPolicyUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/privacy"))
                .merchantUserAgreementUri(Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/legal"));
  PayPalPayment thingToBuy = getThingToBuy(PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(SampleActivity.this, PaymentActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

        intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT);

        return new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal("0.01"), "USD", "sample item",
                paymentIntent);


 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PAYMENT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                PaymentConfirmation confirm =
                        data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
                if (confirm != null) {
                    try {
                        Log.i(TAG, confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
}
}
}
```

The problem is similar to the below

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/issues/330

No idea how to solve this.

Comment: Which paypal version you are using?

Comment: The latest one 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'

Comment: Okey. Where is the code for startService() ?

Comment: See my answer may be this help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one this is working code of my Google PlayStore application.

```
PayPalConfiguration config = new PayPalConfiguration().environment(PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX).clientId("Your id");

Intent intent = new Intent(context, PayPalService.class);
intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
startService(intent);

PayPalPayment payment = new PayPalPayment(new BigDecimal(charge), "USD", eventName, PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, PaymentActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);
intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, payment);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1089);
```

Don't Forget to stop service in OnDestroy().

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Also stop service inside OnActivityResult When you perform all your task.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 1089) {
        PaymentConfirmation confirm = data.getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
        if (confirm != null)
        {
            try
            {
                // Your code after successful response.                    
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.error(getClass().getName(), e);
            }
        }
        stopService(new Intent(this, PayPalService.class));
    } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        //
    } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I am trying.But what is not I am getting is that I have picked the code from the sample PayPal GitHub.So it should work.Though I will check the code and will revert back.

Comment: Sorry same response getting from server.

Comment: Please verify your paypal sandbox account. It is properly configured or not.

Comment: I was used this version for above code. compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.1'

Comment: Try to change the lower version and try it out.